# Angularjs - repeater appending elements in different parents in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know that if I use the directive ng-repeat, like below, I get every element inside and including the div to repeat on the DOM.

```
 <div class="col col-3" ng-repeat="movie in popular" >
                <figure>
                <img ng-src="{{movie.backdropURL}}" alt="{{movie.code}}">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <figcaption>{{movie.code}}</figcaption>
                    <!-- <span class="extra-info">{{movie.extra}}</span> -->
                    <span class="price">{{movie.price}}</span>
                </figure>
            </div>
```

However now I want to have some parent elements that won't repeat but will use the same scope object for their children, that will then repeat.
So, I would like to do a repeater that would append the properties of the scope into their parent, something like this:

```
<ul class="parent1">
   <li><img src={{myScope[0].imgUrl}}></li>
   <li><img src={{myScope[1].imgUrl}}></li>
   <li><img src={{myScope[2].imgUrl}}></li>
</ul>
<div class="parent2">
   <span>{{myScope[0].description}}</span>
   <span>{{myScope[1].description}}</span>
   <span>{{myScope[2].description}}</span>
</div>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to reuse a native angular directive (I would prefer not to run the same repeater every time for every parent) where it could append the element to the parent. If not, do you have any suggestion for a solution. I've looked up some links for custom directives I haven't succeeded in applying them. So if you have a 'beginners' custom directive tutorial that could help me go on the right direction, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand exactly what you are asking for. 
Anyway, the ngRepeat directive is placed in the DOM under a particular parent, so you cannot run it once and append the leaves under different parents. The only way to do that is to create a custom directive that runs a loop internally and sets the leaf under the parent of your choice.
That is:

```
angular
  .module('mymodule')
  .directive('mydirective', mydirective);

function mydirective(){
  var directive = {
                restrict: 'A'
              , link: link
  }

  return directive;

  function link($scope, elem, attrs) {
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.myScope.length;++i){
      var el1 = angular.element('<li><img src='+$scope.myScope[i].imgUrl+'></li>'),
          el2 = angular.element('<span>'+$scope.myScope[i].description+'</span>');
      elem.find('.parent1').append(el1);
      elem.find('.parent2').append(el2);
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul class="parent1">
    <li ng-repeat="item in myScope">
      <img ng-src={{item.imgUrl}}>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="parent2">
     <p ng-repeat="item in myScope"><span>{{item.description}}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myScope = [
      {imgUrl:"someUrl1", description: "this is first url"},
      {imgUrl:"someUrl2", description: "this is second url"}
    ]
  }]);
```

Acceptable :) ?

Comment: Thanks ZenDD, that was my first option, since I didn't know any other way. As I mentioned "I would prefer not to run the same repeater every time for every parent". Although the above should work, it's not ideal to repeat the repeater as many times as the amount of parents in my opinion. So I am trying the first answer, if it works that should be a more fitted answer.